# How to present a UIViewController on top of UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that displays a thumbnail of an images.  When I tap on this cell(thumbnail) I use the function below to push on another `UIViewController` that then enables be to download and view an enlarged image of the thumbnail. I have a `UIButton` within each cell. I would like to present another `viewController` that will act as a custom pop up that I hope to display more detail about the image e.g file name, date etc... When set an `action` connection to a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class, and within the `IBAction` function method, I am not able to 'present' this custom `UIViewController`. `Xcode` just doesn't recogize 'present'. Please can someone advise?

```
 class CollectionViewFolder: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

 ...

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

     }

 ...
 }
```

Custom:

```
 class CollectionViewFolderCell: UICollectionViewCell {

      @IBAction func moreInfoBtn(_ sender: Any) {

           // DOES NOT RECOGNIZE 'present' - TO PRESENT ANOTHER UIVIEWCONTROLLER

       }


 }
```

Comment: To present a `UIViewController` you have to be a `UIViewController`. So add a delegate, or a closure to `CollectionViewFolderCell` that can tell `CollectionViewFolder` to present that new `UIViewController` with the needed informations.

Comment: This is not right way to present VC in a cell class. First thing VC can present another VC. So the solution here is on button press give a callback to your VC their then you present your other VC.

Comment: Why would your cell need a button when the collectionView already has a delegate method didSelectCellAt, which you even showed in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a protocol in your `CollectionViewFolderCell.swift`

```
protocol CollectionViewFolderCellDelegate {
    func collectionViewFolderCellDidPressButton()
}
```

And inside `CollectionViewFolderCell` declare a delegate like:

```
var delegate: CollectionViewFolderCellDelegate?
```

Inside your button action add:

```
@IBAction func moreInfoBtn(_ sender: Any) {

     delegate?.collectionViewFolderCellDidPressButton()

 }
```

In your cellForItemAtIndexPath Method add `cell.delegate = self`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                          cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewFolderCell
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

Also in your View Controller you need to conform your `CollectionViewFolderCellDelegate`

```
extension CollectionViewFolder: CollectionViewFolderCellDelegate {
    // here you can present your desired view controller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`present(_:animated:completion:)` is a `UIViewController`.
To be able to show (present, push, pop, etc.) another `UIViewController` you have to be a UIViewController (or a specific one in case of push, etc.). So `CollectionViewFolderCell` can't present your new `UIViewController`.

You need then to tell the `UIViewController` (in your case `CollectionViewFolder`)  having your cell (in your case `CollectionViewFolderCell` through its `UICollectionView`) to do so. Do to that, you can use delegate pattern, or a closure.

A quick sample code with closure:

Add a property to `CollectionViewFolderCell`:

```
var onMoreInfoTap: ((ParamTypeOrClass1, ParamTypeOrClass2, etc) -> Void)?
```

Then modify your method:

```
@IBAction func moreInfoBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    //Compute all your params, let's name them param1, param2, etc.
    self.onMoreInfoTap?(param1, param2, etc.   
}
```

On `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`:

```
cell.onMoreInfoTap = { [weak self] (param1Name, param2Name, etc) in 
     let viewController = //Create your target UIViewController
     //Set its customs var according to Param1Name, Param2Name, etc.
     self?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```